# g++ optimization bug on osx using -O3

Tags: c++, macos, optimization, gcc, g++

The following code produces the wrong exit code when compiled with -O3.  I think the inner loop is being optimized away incorrectly.  With -O2 or -fno-inline it works.  Producing a simpler example is difficult because any small changes and the bug disappears.

Compiled with:

```
/usr/bin/g++ -O3 -o bugexample bugexample.cpp
```

Code:

```
#include <vector>

int test(std::vector<char>& a, int& b)
{
    std::vector<int> z;
    z.push_back(10);
    z.push_back(10);

    int d = (int)a.size();

    int x = 1;
    for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++)
    {
        int c = j - 1;

        for (int i = 0; i < d; i++) 
        {
            if (j == 0)
            {
            }
            else if (i == 0)
            {
            }
            else
            {
                if (a[j] == a[i - 1])
                {
                    b = c + 1;
                    x = 2;
                }
                z[i] = 1;
            }
        }
    }

    return x;
}


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::vector<char> a;
    a.push_back('a');
    a.push_back('a');
    int b = 1;
    return test(a,b);
}
```

Compiler version:

```
/usr/bin/g++ -v
Using built-in specs.
Target: i686-apple-darwin10
Configured with: /var/tmp/gcc/gcc-5666.3~123/src/configure --disable-checking --enable-werror --prefix=/usr --mandir=/share/man --enable-languages=c,objc,c++,obj-c++ --program-transform-name=/^[cg][^.-]*$/s/$/-4.2/ --with-slibdir=/usr/lib --build=i686-apple-darwin10 --program-prefix=i686-apple-darwin10- --host=x86_64-apple-darwin10 --target=i686-apple-darwin10 --with-gxx-include-dir=/include/c++/4.2.1
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)
```

Interested in any insite, or proof that its my fault.

Edit: The exit code produced is 1, whereas it should b 2.

Comment: What do you expect the program to do, and what is it doing wrong?

Comment: What value does it produce?  What value should it produce?

Comment: if you know it is a bug, just report it upstream. We don't take bug reports.

Comment: i'm pretty convinced this is not a bug. It looks like heavily flawed code. I can't really spot the undefined behaviour but I have provided an analysis of peculiar things in the `test` function

Comment: *"I think the inner loop is being optimized away incorrectly."* Have you considered looking at the generated assembly? Use `gcc -S`.

Comment: Your code works fine for me (i.e. exits with status 2) at all optimization levels with `i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-g++-4.2 (GCC) 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2336.1.00)` on Mac OS X v10.7.2.

Comment: Code is correct. Either a compiler bug or exit code does not get properly passed all the way to the shell.

Answer (score 1):

Mmm is this some kind of obfuscated code contest?

As far as I can tell you're trying to do some kind of palindrome test on the input vector. Only,

- the loop var `j` has a hardcoded upperbound of `2` (which should probably have been a.size() as well?)
- you only return the check of the last position
- you had all kinds of redundant conditions
- you had gratuitous non-const arguments
- you had unused `z` vector
- you had unnecessary use of int for bool (1=>false - not found, 2=>true - found)
- you had unnecessary use of out parameter `b`; I replaced that `bool` return type with the value of `b` (with b==-1 indicating no match found)

When simplifying the code for these things, I get this code, and (like your own code) it behaves identically for all optimization levels on g++ 4.6.1:

```
#include <vector>

int test(const std::vector<char>& a)
{
    /* int j = 1; // was: for (int j = 1; j < 2; j++) */

    for (int i = a.size()-1; i > 1; i--) 
        if (a[1] == a[i - 1])
            return 1;

    return -1;
}


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::vector<char> a(2, 'a');
    int b = test(a);

    return b==-1? 1 : 2;
}
```

Comment: Sure, but I can optimise the whole thing even further: `int main() { return 2; }`!  Presumably the OP has arrived at this weird code because it's the simplest he could make it and still demonstrate his problem.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: only if you assume the input is fixed

Comment: It is fixed; the OP's program doesn't use any input.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: You don't get it :) I'm trying to work out what the weird `test` function was supposed to do. My guess is, this is homework, and my hints should help the OP spot a few of the problems. (Of course, when you are taking the question literally, I shouldn't be refactoring/analyzing his code, but instead looking at the compiler output). So, I skipped the question. Sue me.

Comment: Ok, but like you say, this doesn't really answer the question!

Comment: Your version of `test` has a return type of `bool`, and both 1 and -1 convert to true, so it always returns true.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: right! any change, even removing superfluous code, makes it such that the program correctly returns with 2.

Comment: @sehe: It used to be a simple dynamic programming sequence alignment tool, now mangled.  Not homework, but a small piece of my thesis.

Comment: @DerekLedbetter: Ah I see it now, ; I had refactored in tiny steps (_comme il faut_) and changing the `int& b` into the return parameter came last. Forgot to update the proto and (perhaps) the explanation on StackOverflow... Sorry about that

Comment: @user1068490: to date we have, unfortunately, found no-one who was able to [corroborate](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/corroborate) the testimony.